# Pong Created in Python Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, pong

I'm new to Python but I've coded in other languages, mainly for hardware. I made pong in Python using turtle but it's a little glitchy. I was wondering if any of you could check it out and give advice. I also want to add a start screen and end screen but am a little unsure how to. Also if you have any advice on how to improve collision detection, please let me know.

I'm pasting code below

---

```
import os
import math
import random
import time

#set up screen
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgcolor("green")
screen.title("Pong")

# set up border
border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("white")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
border_pen.pendown()
border_pen.pensize(3)
for side in range(4):
    border_pen.fd(600)
    border_pen.lt(90)
border_pen.hideturtle()

#set score to 0
score = 0

#set time to zero
time = 0
seconds = 0

#Draw score
score_pen = turtle.Turtle()
score_pen.speed(0)
score_pen.color("white")
score_pen.penup()
score_pen.setposition(-290, 310)
scorestring = "Score %s" %score
score_pen.write(scorestring, False, align="left", font=     ("Arial", 14, "normal"))
score_pen.hideturtle()

#Draw timer
time_pen = turtle.Turtle()
time_pen.speed(0)
time_pen.color("white")
time_pen.penup()
time_pen.setposition(260, 310)
timestring = "Time %s" %time
time_pen.write(timestring, False, align="left", font= ("Arial", 14, "normal"))
time_pen.hideturtle()

#create the player turtle
player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("blue")
player.shape("square")
player.shapesize(0.5, 4)
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(-280,-250)#(x,y)
player.setheading(90)
playerspeed = 15

#create the AIplayer turtle
AIplayer = turtle.Turtle()
AIplayer.color("black")
AIplayer.shape("square")
AIplayer.shapesize(0.5, 4)
AIplayer.penup()
AIplayer.speed(0)
AIplayer.setposition(280,250)#(x,y)
AIplayer.setheading(90)
AIplayerspeed = 15


#create the pong
pong = turtle.Turtle()
pong.color("red")
pong.shape("circle")
pong.shapesize(0.5, 0.5)
pong.penup()
pong.speed(10)
pong.setposition(0,0)#(x,y)
pongspeed = 15
pong.goto(0, 265)
pong.dy = -5
pong.dx = 5


#Move player up and down
def move_up():
    y = player.ycor()
    y += playerspeed
    if y > 265:
        y = 260
    player.sety(y)

def move_down():
    y = player.ycor()
    y -= playerspeed
    if y < -265:
        y = -260
    player.sety(y)

#keyboard bindings
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(move_up, "Up")
turtle.onkey(move_down, "Down")
#turtle.onkey(fire_bullet, "space")

def isCollision(t1, t2):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(t1.xcor()-    t2.xcor(),2)+math.pow(t1.ycor()-t2.ycor(),2))
    if distance < 20:
        return True
    else:
        return False

#main game loop
while True:

    #move pong ball
    pong.sety(pong.ycor() +pong.dy)
    pong.setx(pong.xcor() +pong.dx)

    #check for bounce and redirect it
    if pong.ycor() < -300:
        pong.dy *= -1
    if pong.ycor() > 300:
        pong.dy *= -1
    if pong.xcor() < -300:
        pong.dx *= -1
        print("Game Over")
        exit()
    if pong.xcor() > 300:
        pong.dx *= -1

    #move AI paddle (might speed up pong movement)
    y = pong.ycor()
    y += AIplayerspeed
    AIplayer.sety(y)
    if AIplayer.ycor() > 265:
        AIplayerspeed *= -1       
    if AIplayer.ycor() < -250:
        AIplayerspeed *= -1

    #collision pong and player
    if isCollision(pong, player):
        pong.dy *= -1
        pong.dx *= -1
        #Update the score
        score += 10
        scorestring = "Score: %s" %score
        score_pen.clear()
        score_pen.write(scorestring, False, align="left", font=("Arial", 14, "normal"))

    #collision pong and AIplayer
    if isCollision(pong, AIplayer):
        pong.dy *= -1
        pong.dx *= -1

    #updates timer and increases ball speed
    if seconds > 29:
        pong.dy *= -2
        pong.dx *= -2

    if seconds > 59:
        pong.dy *= -3
        pong.dx *= -3

     #displays timer but makes game laggy
#    seconds += 0.1
#    time = seconds
#    timestring = "Time: %s" %time
#    time_pen.clear()
#    time_pen.write(timestring, False, align="Left", font=("Arial", 14, "normal"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Some issues I see:

- You've stretched a 20 by 20 square to be 10 by 80:

  AIplayer.shapesize(0.5, 4)

  But your collision distance is only 20 from center, so your ball can
  cross over the bottom or top of the paddle without actually
  colliding.
- Your `isCollision()` function is mostly redundant with turtle's own
  `.collision()` method.
- You shouldn't have `while True:` in an event-driven world like turtle
  as it potentially prevents some events from firing.  Better to
  replace it with a timer event.
- Some of your collisions change both x and y deltas when they should
  only change one of them.
- You should avoid redundant queries of the turtle in your main loop as well as checking conditions that are negated by other logic clauses.  I.e. do as little as you can get away with in the main loop.

Below is my rework of your game along the above lines, plus lots of other style and logic changes:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

FONT = ("Arial", 16, "normal")

def isCollision(t1, t2):
    return t1.distance(t2) < 15

# set up screen
screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("darkgreen")
screen.title("Pong")

# set up border
border_pen = Turtle(visible=False)
border_pen.speed('fastest')
border_pen.color('white')
border_pen.pensize(3)

border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300, -300)
border_pen.pendown()

for _ in range(4):
    border_pen.forward(600)
    border_pen.left(90)

# set score to 0
score = 0

# set time to zero
seconds = 0

# Draw score
score_pen = Turtle(visible=False)
score_pen.color("white")
score_pen.penup()
score_pen.setposition(-290, 310)

score_pen.write("Score {}".format(score), False, align="left", font=FONT)

# Draw timer
time_pen = Turtle(visible=False)
time_pen.color("white")
time_pen.penup()
time_pen.setposition(260, 310)

time_pen.write("Time {}".format(int(seconds)), False, align="left", font=FONT)

# create the player turtle
player = Turtle("square", visible=False)
player.shapesize(0.5, 3)
player.speed('fastest')
player.setheading(90)
player.color("blue")
player.penup()

player.setposition(-280, -250)  # (x,y)
player.showturtle()

playerspeed = 15

# create the AIplayer turtle
AIplayer = Turtle("square", visible=False)
AIplayer.shapesize(0.5, 3)
AIplayer.speed('fastest')
AIplayer.setheading(90)
AIplayer.color("black")
AIplayer.penup()

AIplayer.setposition(280, 250)  # (x,y)
AIplayer.showturtle()

AIplayerspeed = 15

# create the pong
pong = Turtle("circle", visible=False)
pong.shapesize(0.5, 0.5)
pong.speed('fast')
pong.color("red")
pong.penup()

pong.sety(265)
pong.showturtle()

pongspeed = 15
pong_dx, pong_dy = 5, -5

# Move player up and down
def move_up():
    player.forward(playerspeed)

    y = player.ycor()

    if y > 265:
        y = 260
        player.sety(y)

    screen.update()

def move_down():
    player.backward(playerspeed)

    y = player.ycor()

    if y < -265:
        y = -260
        player.sety(y)

    screen.update()

# keyboard bindings
screen.onkey(move_up, "Up")
screen.onkey(move_down, "Down")

screen.listen()

# main game loop
def move():
    global pong_dx, pong_dy, AIplayerspeed, seconds, score

    # move pong ball
    x, y = pong.position()
    x += pong_dx
    y += pong_dy
    pong.setposition(x, y)

    if isCollision(pong, player): # collision pong and player
        pong_dx *= -1
        # Update the score
        score += 10
        score_pen.undo()
        score_pen.write("Score: {}".format(score), align="left", font=FONT)
    elif isCollision(pong, AIplayer):  # collision pong and AIplayer
        pong_dx *= -1
    elif y < -300 or y > 300:  # check for bounce and redirect it
        pong_dy *= -1
    elif x > 300:
        pong_dx *= -1
    elif x < -300:
        print("Game Over")
        screen.bye()
        return

    # move AI paddle (might speed up pong movement)
    AIplayer.forward(AIplayerspeed)

    y = AIplayer.ycor()

    if y < -250 or y > 250:
        AIplayerspeed *= -1

    # display timer
    seconds += 0.05
    time_pen.undo()
    time_pen.write("Time: {}".format(int(seconds)), False, align="Left", font=FONT)
    screen.ontimer(move, 50)

    screen.update()

screen.tracer(False)
move()
screen.mainloop()
```

I couldn't make sense of your "increases ball speed" logic so I left it out.  I used a darker background color as the original was difficult to look at on my screen.

Answer (score 1):

The issue related to the **pong/ball speed** can be due to your CPU. The ball moves 5 pixels in both (x and y) direction every screen update and the update rate  depends on the CPU speed. The processes being executed by the CPU aren't constant and thus the CPU speed fluctuates.  Also because we have `screen.tracer()` set to `False` it doesn't show animations. *Thus, due to lack of animation and inconsistency of CPU speed, we see the speed of pong/ball increasing/decreasing.*

For `screen.tracer()` explanation refer https://youtu.be/LH8WgrUWG_I?t=123

For "the increasing speed" explanation refer https://youtu.be/Hw1H3rG3POM?t=40

To get a bit more consistent behavior, you could add *a long enough pause* into your loop in order to offset the variability of the computing times and to avoid drawing useless frames. You can do this using `time`

```
import time

# Initialization
...

while True:
     time.sleep(1 / 60)

    # The rest of your game logic
...
```

Comment: `ontimer` shown in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51645036/6243352) is preferred to `while True: sleep()`.